# Run MSBuild from Command Line task in Azure Devops

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I'm trying to execute `msbuild` on Azure Devops. Because of that I cannot use the `MSBuild` task provided.

When I use a Command Line task the command is not recognised. On my local machine I load `vcvarsall.bat` before I use `msbuild`. But I've not been unable to work out how to obtain that path in Azure Devops. Doesn't appear to be a `Develop Command Prompt` task for Azue Devops either.

Any ideas on how I can use `msbuild` from a Command Line task or Batch Script task? Using their Hosted VS agent.

Comment: Why can't you use the msbuild task provided?

Comment: @Matt - because I need to invoke it with different command line parameters based on some other conditional logic in my build system.

Comment: Hi thomthom, did below reply solved your concern?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this in a supported way is to use `vswhere`. The following bit of script will install vswhere (using chocolatey) and then query the installer registry where msbuild can be found. Replace `-latest` with a more specific version if you need that:

```
choco install vswhere
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('vswhere -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe -nologo') do set msbuildpath="%%i"

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=msbuildpath]%msbuildpath%"
```

This will save the path to msbuild to the environment variable `%msbuildpath%` as well as the pipeline variable (for this stage) `$(msbuildpath)`.

You can then either use a second run commandline task and pass in `$(msbuildpath)` or you can simply call MsBuild from the same piece of script mentioned above by calling:

```
%msbuildpath%
```

This will make sure your script will remain working, even if Microsoft upgrades their images and moves some things around (which does happen).

You can also get vswhere using `wget` or `invoke-webrequest -outfile` from the following location:

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/releases/latest/download/vswhere.exe
```

Other [samples for `vswhere` syntax can be found on the project wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild), including the syntax for PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Hosted Agent 2017 you can run the `msbuild.exe` from the Command Line task in this way:

Command Line version 1:
[image]

Command Line version 2:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: It has to be Version 1 of the Command Line task? I'm using v2 because I need to apply some conditional logic before I invoke msbuild. Also is that path documented? Or is that an implementation detail that might change?

Comment: @Matt - that's interesting. I was looking for variables, but I'd not found any. I might try that. I also found some clues when inspecting a Build with the system.debug flag on. There's a utility the MSBuild task uses to find and determine the MSBuild version to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in seeing how the built-in Microsoft task resolves the path, all the Azure Devops tasks are provided open-source.  These are the [path functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/MSBuildHelpers/PathFunctions.ps1) you probably care to review.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I came up with using only built-in pipeline tasks which makes the MSBuild bin directory available on the path environment variable.

Create a PowerShell task to generate an MSBuild project to capture and output to a file the variables you are interested in (ex. MSBuildBinPath)

PowerShell script

```
"<Project DefaultTargets=`"DetectMsBuild`">
    <ItemGroup>        
        <OutFile Include=`"`$(MsBuildDetectionFile)`" />
        <OutFile Condition=`"'`$(OutFile)' == ''`" Include=`"msbuildInfo.json`" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name=`"DetectMsBuild`">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MsBuildPaths>
[{
    `"Name`": `"BinPath`",
    `"Value`": `"`$(MSBuildBinPath.Replace('\', '\\'))`"
}]
            </MsBuildPaths>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <WriteLinesToFile
            File=`"@(Outfile)`"
            Lines=`"`$(MsBuildPaths)`"
            Overwrite=`"true`"
            Encoding=`"UTF-8`" />
    </Target>
</Project>" | Out-File -FilePath "msbuilddetect.proj" -Encoding utf8
```

Set the working directory and any variables accordingly.

*PowerShell task settings screenshot*:

[image: PowerShell task settings screenshot]

Create an MSBuild task to run the project file generated by the previous task. Ensure the MSBuild version is set to the version you want to use.

*MSBuild task settings screenshot*:

[image: MSBuild task settings screenshot]

Last, create another PowerShell task that will parse the outputted JSON file of the extracted variables and sets environment variables accordingly.

PowerShell script

```
Write-Host "Current path: $($env.Path)`n`n"

$msBuildVariables = Get-Content -Path msbuildInfo.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$Path = "$($msBuildVariables[0].Value);$($env:Path)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Path;]$Path"
```

*PowerShell task settings screenshot*:

[image: PowerShell task settings screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the task order in the build pipeline.

[image: Pipeline task order screenshot]